# How to properly reuse a session while multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-requests, multiprocessing

I have some python code that is listening to a socket connection and processes tasks that it receives via that socket. The python code has a multiprocessing pool in it that takes care of these tasks. (A task is assigned to some process in the pool)

These tasks involve an API request and I noticed that each time it is doing a task it is repeating the handshake (whereas it should reuse the session).

To make sure the processes are not interfering with one another I tried to give each process it's own session. But for some reason I do not get that to work.

My attempt

```
import multiprocessing
import requests


def init_pool():
    global s
    s = requests.Session()
    print(s)


def f():
    print(s)


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4, initializer=init_pool )



res= pool.map(f,[1,2,3,4])
```

When looking at the print in the function `f` you can notice that the sessions are actually the same. Which surprised my because this code

```
import multiprocessing
import random


def init_pool():
    global r
    r = random.random()


def f():
    print(r)


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4, initializer=init_pool )



res= pool.map(f,[1,2,3,4])
```

does print distinct values.

My question is how can I reuse a session in a multiprocessing pool the right way? (preventing repeated handshakes)

Comment: How many tasks do you have? A handshake will need to be performed for each process in the pool.

Comment: I've figured out what is going on with the Sessions, but I think that does not clarify what is taking place with your handshakes. Maybe the client code for the API does not "know" that the session it is using already completed the handshake?  It maybe be a matter of storing some of the client's api state in the global process state as well.

Comment: I haven't used ```multiprocessing.Pool``` but typically information, like session data, cannot be shared between processes.  To access the same session you would need one process to dedicate itself to the session and have other processes transferring data to the session process.  ```sys.stdin``` ```sys.stdout``` are useful for this.  If the below solution doesn't work, ping me and I'll post a possible solution.

Comment: @alvrm I indeed do not think the processes can share a single session. That is why I'm trying to make them each use a different session. Having only one process managing the session is not ideal as the API request is quite time consuming, so doing it in parallel is important

Answer (score 3):

What is taking place there is that Multiprocessing Pool actually delays the creation of workers until they are needed, or there is some "idle" time.

By simply adding more information to the prints, that is clearly visible - what is taking place is that the single line tasks finish so fast they are actually all running in the first, and same, worker, before multprocessing find the need to spin-off other workers.

By printing the process identification, along with session Id, and a uniquely guaranteed random number that does not depend on S.O. assigned memspawnory addresses to the worker, as well as attributing the prints to the init or tasks phases of a process, this is clearly visible:

```
import multiprocessing
import requests
import random

def init_pool():
    global s
    s = requests.Session()
    s.myid = random.randint(0, 1000)
    print(f"init - {multiprocessing.current_process()}  session id: {id(s)}, myid: {s.myid}")


def f(x):
    print(f"worker - {multiprocessing.current_process()}  session id: {id(s)}, myid: {s.myid}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4, initializer=init_pool )
    res= pool.map(f,[1,2,3,4])
```

Which will print, for example:

```
init - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=20870 started daemon>  session id: 139938864231504, myid: 509
worker - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=20870 started daemon>  session id: 139938864231504, myid: 509
worker - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=20870 started daemon>  session id: 139938864231504, myid: 509
worker - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=20870 started daemon>  session id: 139938864231504, myid: 509
worker - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=20870 started daemon>  session id: 139938864231504, myid: 509
init - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-2' parent=20870 started daemon>  session id: 139910687835472, myid: 747
init - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=20870 started daemon>  session id: 139784626402384, myid: 803
init - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-3' parent=20870 started daemon>  session id: 140676029002576, myid: 359
```

Now, if I add a `time.sleep(0.5)` call inside `f`, allowing the execution of `Pool.map` actually create the other processes before submitting the next task, the result is this:

```
init - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-3' parent=20939 started daemon>  session id: 139733583964496, myid: 741
init - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-2' parent=20939 started daemon>  session id: 140209458611728, myid: 157
init - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=20939 started daemon>  session id: 140097358576912, myid: 178
init - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=20939 started daemon>  session id: 140214050276880, myid: 952
worker - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-2' parent=20939 started daemon>  session id: 140209458611728, myid: 157
worker - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=20939 started daemon>  session id: 140214050276880, myid: 952
worker - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=20939 started daemon>  session id: 140097358576912, myid: 178
worker - <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-3' parent=20939 started daemon>  session id: 139733583964496, myid: 741
```

(Also, I've forced the mp to create subprocesses by using `spawn`, which is the default on Windows and MacOS. As I am running this on Linux, the default would be `fork`, which does not display the "run in the first Pool process" behavior)

Comment: Actually also when I add an explicit wait in the function f I notice that the sessions are still the same (and when called repeatedly do not cache the handshake, probably because the processes interfere with eachother on the same session.) The manual created ids are indeed distinct, but all workers still seem to use the same session.

Comment: that sounds actually strange: sessions in different processes can not be the same. Is it possible that there is another layer of HTTP caching on your system which could be trying to cache the  sessions to the same foreign host on its own?

Answer (score 1):

So this actually seems to solve the issue

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import requests
import time

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()


pool_size = 4
for i in np.arange(pool_size):
    queue.put(i)

sessions = []
for i in np.arange(pool_size):
    sessions = sessions + [requests.Session()]

def init_pool():
    global sessionId
    
    sessionId = queue.get()
    print(sessionId)


def f(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    global sessionId
    print(sessionId)
    print(sessions[sessionId])


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4, initializer=init_pool )



res= pool.map(f,np.arange(10))
```

Here you will see that different sessions are printed.

Whereas in this case you will observe that they are actually the same session

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import requests
import time

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()


pool_size = 4
for i in np.arange(pool_size):
    queue.put(requests.Session())




def init_pool():
    global s
    
    s = queue.get()
    print(s)


def f(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(s)


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4, initializer=init_pool )



res= pool.map(f,np.arange(10))
```

I do not know why these two code blocks work differently, but the first instance works as expected (no repeated handshakes) and the second one does not.

Comment: you know Pythonhas the built-in "range", right? no need to call "np.arange" for a simple count-to-4

Comment: just a small note, i know you have learned that numpy is faster than python, this is not always the case , and as a matter of fact if you are working on small structures of less than 100 elements you will find that pure python with lists and python built-ins is faster than numpy, even for arithmetic, and obviously python's `range` is going to be faster and more memory efficient than numpy's `arange`, unless you are specifically passing it to numpy functions for further processing.